# How to list all acl permissions set in the system?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, acl

with `getfacl` I can list the ownerships of any file or directory. But I want a list of all the files and directories that have been modified through acl to have more than one owner.

I know that `getfacl -R /` would technically give me the list I want. But its the permissions of the ENTIRE system. I only want the files and directories that have more than one owner.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "special permissions"? Are you wanting to list the objects that have permissions that match a specific set, to find all the permissions of objects that differ from default, or something else?

Comment: I modified the question, I hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getfacl --skip-base`.

Note that additional users in the ACL do not result in "more than one owner". They do not receive owner-specific privileges such as the ability to chmod() a file or alter ACLs, and the file isn't accounted to their disk quota.